# C++ standard algorithm to separate an expression into 2 expressions separated by an operator of lowest precedence?

Tags: c++

The class I'm making requires a function which I've detailed in the comments inside:

```
bool CalculusWizard::partitionEquation(const std::string & eq, std::string & eq1, std::string & eq2, CalcWizConsts::eqOps & oper)
{
    /* Given an equation eq, partion eq into 
       eq = eq1 oper eq2
       where oper is the operator with the lowest precedence, 
       e.g. eq = "x*sin(x)+x^2" --> eq1 = "x*sin(x)", oper = ADDITION, eq2 = "x^2".
       If there is no operator, e.g. eq = "x", then oper = NONE.
       The error checking is done in this function. If there is a syntactical error 
       in eq, then return false.
    */
    bool eqGood = true; 
    eq1.clear();
    eq2.clear();
    oper = CalcWizConsts::NONE;
    std::string::const_iterator it(eq.begin()), offend(eq.end());
    while (it != offend)
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    return eqGood;

}
```

which uses an enumerator `enum eqOps { ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION, COMPOSITION, NONE };` defined inside namespace `CalcWizConsts`. The functions that can be found in the expression are `sin(...)`, `cos(...)`, `e^(...)`, and `log(...)`. For an example of how the operator `COMPOSITION` words, the function log(x^2) would be partitioned into `eq1=log(x)` and `eq2=x^2` with `oper=COMPOSITION`.

I was originally going to try and write my own procedure, but I've caved in and decided to see if this type of thing is a solved problem whose solution is accessible to me in some sort of general library algorithm that you may know of. Can you lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you talking about [this algorithm](http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html)?

Comment: What you are trying to do is grammar parsing and it's done in a completely different manner, but your way will work too if you want to stick to your idea.

Comment: I think you are thinking of reverse polish notation

Comment: @System.exit: You linked to several algorithms, none of which appear to be what the OP is doing.  Every algorithm I've ever heard of was single-pass, but the OP seems to have invented a new `log(N)` pass algorithm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at Recursive Descent Parser for inspiration, you need to feed it tokens of identifiers eg) x, sin, cos, e^, log, operators eg) +, -, *, / from a lexical analysis function which reads a string.  The explanation of COMPOSITION operator seems strange, the contents of ( ... ) would appear to be composed into an expression, so the functions operates on a unary expression.